# How to get deviation from a reference value for multindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm interested in finding deviations from my simulated data from experiment, in a manner similar to the following:

```
my_frame = pd.DataFrame(data={'simulation1':[71,4.8,65,4.7],
                              'simulation2':[71,4.8,69,4.7],
                              'simulation3':[70,3.8,68,4.9],
                              'experiment':[70.3,3.5,65,4.4],
                              'Material':['Copper','Copper',
                                        'Aluminum','Aluminum'],
                              'Property':['Temperature','Weight',
                                        'Temperature','Weight']})
my_frame.set_index(keys=['Material','Property'], inplace=True)


                         simulation1 simulation2 simulation3 experiment
Material    Property                
Copper      Temperature  71.0        71.0        70.0        70.3
Weight                   4.8         4.8         3.8         3.5
Aluminum    Temperature  65.0        69.0        68.0        65.0
Weight                   4.7         4.7         4.9         4.4
```

I would like to have a per-category deviation from a reference column (in my case experiment)

```
                         simulation1 simulation2 simulation3 experiment
Material    Property                
Copper      Temperature  71.0        71.0        70.0        70.3
Weight                   4.8         4.8         3.8         3.5
ERROR(Weight-exp)        0.7         0.7         0.3         0.0
ERROR(Temp  -exp)        1.3         1.3         0.3         0.0

Aluminum    Temperature  65.0        69.0        68.0        65.0
Weight                   4.7         4.7         4.9         4.4
ERROR(Weight-exp)        0.0         4.0         3.0         0.0
ERROR(Temp  -exp)        0.3         0.3         0.5         0.0
```

I'm sure this can be done easily(ish) in pandas, but I"m not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new DataFrame by subtract column `experiment` by [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) and then change `MultiIndex`:

```
df = my_frame.sub(my_frame['experiment'], axis=0)
a = df.index.get_level_values(0) + '_ERR'
b = df.index.get_level_values(1)

df.index = [a, b]
print (df)
                          simulation1  simulation2  simulation3  experiment
Material     Property                                                      
Copper_ERR   Temperature          0.7          0.7         -0.3         0.0
             Weight               1.3          1.3          0.3         0.0
Aluminum_ERR Temperature          0.0          4.0          3.0         0.0
             Weight               0.3          0.3          0.5         0.0
```

Last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
my_frame = pd.concat([my_frame, df]).sort_index()
print (my_frame)
                          simulation1  simulation2  simulation3  experiment
Material     Property                                                      
Aluminum     Temperature         65.0         69.0         68.0        65.0
             Weight               4.7          4.7          4.9         4.4
Aluminum_ERR Temperature          0.0          4.0          3.0         0.0
             Weight               0.3          0.3          0.5         0.0
Copper       Temperature         71.0         71.0         70.0        70.3
             Weight               4.8          4.8          3.8         3.5
Copper_ERR   Temperature          0.7          0.7         -0.3         0.0
             Weight               1.3          1.3          0.3         0.0
```

Another solution with change second level:

```
df = my_frame.sub(my_frame['experiment'], axis=0)
a = df.index.get_level_values(0)
b = 'ERROR(' + df.index.get_level_values(1) + '-exp)'

df.index = [a, b]
print (df)
                                 simulation1  simulation2  simulation3  \
Material Property                                                        
Copper   ERROR(Temperature-exp)          0.7          0.7         -0.3   
         ERROR(Weight-exp)               1.3          1.3          0.3   
Aluminum ERROR(Temperature-exp)          0.0          4.0          3.0   
         ERROR(Weight-exp)               0.3          0.3          0.5   

                                 experiment  
Material Property                            
Copper   ERROR(Temperature-exp)         0.0  
         ERROR(Weight-exp)              0.0  
Aluminum ERROR(Temperature-exp)         0.0  
         ERROR(Weight-exp)              0.0
```

---

```
my_frame = pd.concat([my_frame, df]).sort_index(ascending=False)
print (my_frame)
                                 simulation1  simulation2  simulation3  \
Material Property                                                        
Copper   Weight                          4.8          4.8          3.8   
         Temperature                    71.0         71.0         70.0   
         ERROR(Weight-exp)               1.3          1.3          0.3   
         ERROR(Temperature-exp)          0.7          0.7         -0.3   
Aluminum Weight                          4.7          4.7          4.9   
         Temperature                    65.0         69.0         68.0   
         ERROR(Weight-exp)               0.3          0.3          0.5   
         ERROR(Temperature-exp)          0.0          4.0          3.0   

                                 experiment  
Material Property                            
Copper   Weight                         3.5  
         Temperature                   70.3  
         ERROR(Weight-exp)              0.0  
         ERROR(Temperature-exp)         0.0  
Aluminum Weight                         4.4  
         Temperature                   65.0  
         ERROR(Weight-exp)              0.0  
         ERROR(Temperature-exp)         0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do a simple difference between the column 'simulations' selected with [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and 'experiment'. [`Rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the index and `concat` with the original data:

```
frame_error = ((my_frame.filter(like='simulation') - my_frame.experiment.values[:,None])
                     .rename(index={idx1: 'ERROR({}-exp)'.format(idx1) 
                                 for idx1 in my_frame.index.get_level_values(1) }, level=1))
print (frame_error)
                                 simulation1  simulation2  simulation3
Material Property                                                     
Copper   ERROR(Temperature-exp)          0.7          0.7         -0.3
         ERROR(Weight-exp)               1.3          1.3          0.3
Aluminum ERROR(Temperature-exp)          0.0          4.0          3.0
         ERROR(Weight-exp)               0.3          0.3          0.5
```

then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) both dataframes:

```
my_frame_all = pd.concat([my_frame, frame_error], axis=0, sort=False).sort_index()
print (my_frame_all)
                                 simulation1  simulation2  simulation3  \
Material Property                                                        
Aluminum ERROR(Temperature-exp)          0.0          4.0          3.0   
         ERROR(Weight-exp)               0.3          0.3          0.5   
         Temperature                    65.0         69.0         68.0   
         Weight                          4.7          4.7          4.9   
Copper   ERROR(Temperature-exp)          0.7          0.7         -0.3   
         ERROR(Weight-exp)               1.3          1.3          0.3   
         Temperature                    71.0         71.0         70.0   
         Weight                          4.8          4.8          3.8   

                                 experiment  
Material Property                            
Aluminum ERROR(Temperature-exp)         NaN  
         ERROR(Weight-exp)              NaN  
         Temperature                   65.0  
         Weight                         4.4  
Copper   ERROR(Temperature-exp)         NaN  
         ERROR(Weight-exp)              NaN  
         Temperature                   70.3  
         Weight                         3.5
```